# ¿Como modificar el nombre de una variable? Javascript

Tags: javascript, bucle-for, variables, javascript-objeto

Tengo un problema con un ejercicio planteado por mi profesor
Me indica que quiere que haga un loop para crear 30 objetos diferentes de manera automática
Pero al momento de usar la función creadora new, me encuentro con un problema
Se reescribe el valor 30 veces sobre la misma variable asignada a la función constructora
Y no encuentro la manera de  por medio de algún código dentro del loop, que se reescriba al reiniciarse el loop el nombre de la variable.

```js
function tests(a, b, c) {
  this.a = a;
  this.b = b;
  this.c = c;
}

function datos() {
  var azar = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100);
  return azar;
}

for (var i = 0, x = 30; i < x; i++) {
  var usuario = "usuario" + i;
  nombre = datos();
  informacion = datos();
  determinante = datos();
  var usuario = new tests(determinante, informacion, nombre);
  console.log("Primera etapa");
  console.log(usuario);
}
```

> tengo los console.log para tener una retroalimentacion de que esta ocurriendo cuando lo ejecuto en la consola.

Comment: ¿Porque repites una función 3 veces? *Don't repeat yourself*. Por otro lado, puedes almacenar cada objeto como elemento de un `Array`, es la forma más adecuada cuando son tantos objetos. Saludos

Comment: Concuerdo con el compañero @MauricioContreras, debido a que tus tres funciones hacen lo mismo, no tiene mucho sentido tenerla dos veces más puesto que al ser un random, el resultado será diferente en cada llamada. Por otro lado, para almacenar cada objeto nuevo generado puedes apoyarte en los arrays, y con [`array.push()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push) puedes agregar un nuevo elemento al array que contendrá todos tus objetos generados.

Comment: Compañeros, el problema que tengo es que debo separar en objetos independientes cada loop del for.
Podria crearlo con un push, pero me quedaria un objeto de 90
Y requiero que me queden 30 objetos de 3, que pueda invocar independientemente

Comment: @Levi crear un arreglo como ya te comentaron, ¿no te sirve? ¿como imaginas/quisieras acceder a cada objeto individualmente?

Comment: @Marcos , llamandolo por ejemplo como intento en el codigo, pero creo que tengo un vacio en mis bases
"usuario"+i 
usuario1
usuario2
usuario3
...
No se si haya una manera mas eficiente de hacerlo

Comment: Lo logre!, no comprendia bien como funcionaba lo de los arreglos, pero ya lo solucione
Son los mejores !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Podrías crear un objeto para guardar las instancias de `tests` creadas.

Para cada instancia creada, podes crear una propiedad con el nombre deseado para identificarla posteriormente.

#### Ejemplo:

```js
function tests(a, b, c) {
  this.a = a;
  this.b = b;
  this.c = c;
}

function datos() {
  var azar = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100);
  return azar;
}

let instancias = {}; // Un objeto vacio

for (var i = 0, x = 30; i < x; i++) {

  nombre = datos();
  informacion = datos();
  determinante = datos();
  var usuario = new tests(determinante, informacion, nombre);

  instancias["usuario" + i] = usuario; // Guardamos la instancia
  // Log para validar
  if (i === 5) console.log('Ini usuario' + i + ' = ', usuario);
}

// Acceder al usuario5 manualmente
console.log('Acceso manual a usuario5 = ', instancias.usuario5);

// o dinámicamente
i = 5;
console.log('Acceso dinamico a usuario' + i + ' = ', instancias['usuario' + i]);
```